# Pundit Authorize From Another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I need to authorize a project based on invites that a supplier has gotten. Supplier has a "user_id" field.

project.rb

```
has_many :invites
has_many :suppliers, :through => :invites
```

project_policy.rb

```
class ProjectPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :project

  def initialize(user, project)
    @user = user
    @project = project
  end

  def show?
    ##need help on the next line##
    if project.joins(:invites).joins(:suppliers).pluck("suppliers.user_id") == user.id
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

How can I show only the appropriate projects based on the `user_id` in the suppliers table? If this needs to be in the scope, then how do I check the `suppliers.user_id` in the scope?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your question. Is that like of code working? if now. What is the problem. Could you show us the result of the query

Comment: Yeah, I have the model relationships set up, but trying to figure out what to put into the `show?` pundit policy so that it only allows access to projects that have an invite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I show only the appropriate projects based on the `user_id` in the suppliers table?

[The has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

```
Invites.rb
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :project
```

Project model has many suppliers

```
Project.rb
  has_many :invites
  has_many :suppliers, :through => :invites
```

Supplier model has many projects

```
Supplier.rb
  has_many :invites
  has_many :projects, :through => :invites
```

Find the supplier and use the `has_many :projects, :through => :invites`

```
Supplier.find_by(user_id: user.id).projects
```

Comment: Based on your hint, made it work with: `Supplier.find_by(user_id:user.id).projects.pluck("projects.id").include? project.id` in the `show?` policy.  Do you think that is DRY enough? If so, can you include it in your answer, and I'll accept..

Comment: @HoosierCoder Yes, but if you need more help you can check codereview stack exchange forum

Comment: @HoosierCoder thanks a lot . Good luck with your app !